# Modal window does not popup on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a **modal popup window** to my Angular app.  Although it lists down the names, when I click on the names a modal doesn't appear. Below is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(customer)">{{ customer.name }}</button> <br />

        <!--MODAL WINDOW--> 
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>The Customer Name is: {{ customer.name }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    This is where the Customer Details Goes<br />
                    {{ customer.details }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </script>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {controller:testcontroller, templateUrl:'http://localhost/app/index.php/customer/home'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/error'});
});

function test2controller ($scope, $modalInstance, customer) {
    $scope.customer = customer;
}

function testcontroller ( $scope, $timeout, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.customers = [
        {
            name: 'Ben',
            details: 'Some Details for Ben',
        },
        {
            name: 'Donald',
            details: 'Some Donald Details',
        },
        {
            name: 'Micky',
            details: 'Some Micky Details',
        }
    ];

    $scope.open = function (_customer) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: "test2controller",
            templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
            resolve: {
                customer: function()
                {
                    return _customer;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd start by moving the script outside of the ng-repeat. Then post a plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: @JBNizet I added it to plunkr but it doesnt show the name list https://plnkr.co/edit/JS1J0Iphv6wmfboO5ik8?p=preview. But shows the list properly in my PC.

Comment: im using codeigniter. so on the html `<script type="text/ng-template" id="myContent.html"> do i need to give the controller URL?`

Comment: I have no idea what codeigniter is. When I create a correct plunkr, with a complete html page loading the right library, with the controllers defined correctly, with the template out of the ng-repeat, and with the right template url, it works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/12JdMF6NaeJjxQsQxqXg?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks alot.. This works :) Need to find a away to get it working property with codeigniter. Codeigniter is a PHP framework

Comment: I 'm learning naw in Angular and i'm not so good but in my opinion in the view you are calling to "costumer.details" but in your js you have costumers, maybe youjust nedd to add an "s" to your view, also i think you wil need to put it (in your view ) inside a ng-repeat to show all costumers details

Answer (score 0):

## Controller

```
$scope.saveFeed = function(feed){
    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    console.log(feed);
}
```

### HTML

```
<a class="dropdown-item p-3" href="#" ng-click="saveFeed(feed.id)">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-top">
        <div class="icon font-size-20"><i class="ri-save-line"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="data ml-2">
            <h6>Save Post</h6>
            <p class="mb-0">Add this to your saved items</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                ...

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```